# How can I increase drawer drag area width in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I have a drawer in my Flutter app, but the default drawer has a very small drag area to show it. How can I increase it?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        drawerDragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
        drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text(
                fullName ?? "",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  letterSpacing: 1.0,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the `drawerEdgeDragWidth` property of the `Scaffold`:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: MyAppBar(),
  drawer: MyDrawer(),
  // Put the width you want here
  // In this case the drag area fills the whole screen
  drawerEdgeDragWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  body: MyBody(),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 drawer: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.2,
        child: Drawer(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text(
                      "Apply for Leave",
                      style: drawerFont,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ApplyLeave()));
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text(
                      "Approval for Bills",
                      style: drawerFont,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ApplyBill()));
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 60,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 28.0, top: 15, bottom: 15),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ContactUs()));
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Contact Us",
                          style: drawerFont,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: But here you are setting the width of the drawer. I need to change the width of the drag area to show the drawer.

Comment: can you tell what do you exectly  want?

Comment: Make the drawer drag width larger. I want to open the drawer by swiping it from left to right in the middle on the screen, but not just in the left corner.